# Error 'ReactCommon/TurboModuleBinding.h' file not found on react native 0.72.0 on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

After upgrading my react native to version 0.72.0, I can't run my react native app on iOS properly as it logs an error saying:
`"Error 'ReactCommon/TurboModuleBinding.h' file"`
as show in the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSym0.png)

I tried executing with the suggestions described [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36739) but unfortunately the error is still here.

## Here is the output of npx react-native info:

```
System:
  OS: macOS 13.4
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
  Memory: 89.31 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.2.0
    path: /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm:
    version: 9.6.6
    path: /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: Not Found
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.12.1
    path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 22.4
      - iOS 16.4
      - macOS 13.3
      - tvOS 16.4
      - watchOS 9.4
  Android SDK:
    API Levels:
      - "28"
      - "29"
      - "30"
      - "31"
      - "32"
      - "33"
    Build Tools:
      - 29.0.2
      - 30.0.2
      - 30.0.3
      - 31.0.0
      - 32.0.0
      - 33.0.0
      - 34.0.0
    System Images:
      - android-28 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      - android-28 | Google ARM64-V8a Play ARM 64 v8a
      - android-29 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      - android-29 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
      - android-30 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      - android-31 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
      - android-32 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      - android-33 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      - android-33 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
    Android NDK: 22.1.7171670
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
  Xcode:
    version: 14.3.1/14E300c
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.1
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 3.2.2
    path: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.0
    wanted: ^0.72.0
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: false
  newArchEnabled: false
```

Any idea on what I can do to fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? There is still no clear solution in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38067? Any idea if a upgrade to 0.73 helps?

Answer (score 0):

could you share your Podfile, please?

How you usually run pod install? We solved the `Error 'ReactCommon/TurboModuleBinding.h' file` already, so there should be some local misconfiguration and I'll be happy to help.

Also, why you opened this on SO, instead of in the [React Native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues) repo? This will make it slightly harder for me to keep an eye on the issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for accepting to help me fix this!
I've created it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38067 and added my Podfile